# How can I find the contents of the first h3 tag?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I am looking for a regex to find the contents of the first `<h3>` tag. What can I use there?

Comment: Using Regexes for this kind of HTML parsing is generally a bad idea. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags Use a proper HTML parser.

Comment: Don't use a regex for HTML/XML parsing.  Use an HTML/XML parser.  Php has a few.

Comment: You can also use xpath for this purpose if you html is xhtml.

Comment: PHP has the ability to parse HTML DOMs natively - you almost certainly want to use that instead of regex.

Comment: Thou shalt not use regular expressions to parse HTML. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php-closed

Comment: I don't know why this is getting down-voted - it's a legitimate question for a newb.

Comment: I agree with the sentiments of avoiding using Regex for this, but I think all the downvotes are bit harsh -- isn't this supposed to be a site where you ask questions because you don't know how to do something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting all values from h1 tags using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299033/getting-all-values-from-h1-tags-using-php)

Comment: *(related)* [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 4):

You should use php's DOM parser instead of regular expressions. You're looking for something like this (untested code warning):

```
$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML($html_content);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$domx = new DOMXPath($domd);
$items = $domx->query("//h3[position() = 1]");

echo $items->item(0)->textContent;
```

Comment: Surely more elegant than my attempt :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, a simple solution would be the following:

```
preg_match( '#<h3[^>]*>(.*?)</h3>#i', $text, $match );
echo $match[1];
```

For everything more complex, you should consider using a HTML document parser though.

Answer (score 3):

The DOM approach:

```
<?php

$html = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Lorem ipsum<h1>
<h2>Dolor sit amet<h2>
<h3>Duis quis velit est<h3>
<p>Cras non tempor est.</p>
<p>Maecenas nec libero leo.</p>
<h3>Nulla eu ligula est</h3>
<p>Suspendisse potenti.</p>

</body>
</html>
';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$titles = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h3');
if( !is_null($titles->item(0)) ){
    echo $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)'s an explanation why parsing HTML with regular expressions is evil. Anyway, this is a way to do it...

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($text);
$headings = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h3');
$heading = $headings->item(0);
$heading_value = (isset($heading->nodeValue)) ? $heading->nodeValue : 'Header not found';
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: regular expressions aren't a proper tool for parsing HTML code. However in this case, they should be good enough, cause `H3` tags cannot be nested.

```
preg_match_all('/<h3[^>]*>(.*?)<\/h3>/si', $source, $matches);
```

`$matches` variable should contains content from `H3` tagas.

Comment: But they can be commented out, or contains the code `<h3 title="Wibble>Wobble">Wibble &gt; Wobble</h3>`, or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Use an xpath expression like

```
"/html/body/h3[0]"
```

this will select the whole first h3 node.

Note that this will not work on ill-formed html.

Comment: With DOM's loadHTML(), this will work fine with real world (read broken) HTML.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has the ability to parse HTML DOMs natively - you almost certainly want to use that instead of regex.

See this page for details: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

And check the related questions down the right hand side for people asking very similar questions.

Answer (score -1):

```
preg_match("/&lt;h3&gt;(.*)&lt;\/h3&gt;/", $search_in_this_string, $put_matches_in_this_var);
```

Comment: Expression here is incorrect (and using regex in general a bad idea)