# Trying to create a menu dynamically with php using preg_match_all to my server php documents

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, arrays

The project consists of a lateral menu, which contains all my blog entries.
In theory, the menu works this way: I get the `<h1>` title of each of my blog documents and his corresponding `href`, using php.

---

So each time i add a new blog entry, it appears in the menu **automatically**,
i did this using **fopen** and **fread** and saving the contents of each php document of my blog in a variable called **$leer**.

---

Then, i used **Preg_match_all** to search the title of each blog entry and display it on the menu. With this I can make the menu without having to add the links manually, also using scandir get the url.

---

The problem is that, when using **preg_match_all** in the array, gives me many incorrect results, obtaining the same `<h1>` title four times without explanation.
Here is the code:

```
$escanear = scandir ("/home/sites/thetoptenweb.com/public_html/post");
$tamanoArray = count($escanear);
```

So first, as you can see, i´m using **scandir** and **count** to get the number of pages.

```
for($i=2;$i<=$tamanoArray-3;$i++){
    $abrirFichero = fopen($escanear[$i],"r");
    $leer=fread($abrirFichero, filesize($escanear[$i]));        
    fclose($abrirFichero);
}
```

Then, i use a **for loop** and **fread** to read all my documents.
The loop is made to "scan" only the selected files between the second and the last-3, because those are my blog entries.

```
preg_match_all('%<h1>(.*)</h1>%', $leer, $arrayMaches);
```

**So, with the `preg_match_all` function i get the Title of my documents in a multi-dimensional array, *that array* is giving me problems *i think*, because i tryed to read each result with `foreach` loops, but there are some blank results and i don´t know why this happens.**

```
foreach ($arrayMaches as $result) {
    foreach ($result as $key) {
    }
}

$cortado=preg_split('%</?h1>%', $key);

echo "<a href=".'"'.$escanear[$i].'"'."><li>".$cortado[0]."</li></a><hr>";
```

Finally, i used **foreach loops** to access to the **multi-dimensional array** of the **preg_match_all**. Then, i **preg_split**ed the results to get the text without html tags and after that, displayed the results with **echo**.

*Hope someone helps me recognizing the problem and, if possible, an explanation to the preg_match_all array because i don´t understand how it´s created. Suggestions admited.*
If you know a better way to do this, i´ll happy to read it.
This is the entire code:

```
<?php
    $escanear = scandir ("/home/sites/thetoptenweb.com/public_html/post");
    $tamanoArray = count($escanear);
    for($i=2;$i<=$tamanoArray-3;$i++){
        $abrirFichero = fopen($escanear[$i],"r");
        $leer=fread($abrirFichero, filesize($escanear[$i]));
        fclose($abrirFichero);
        preg_match_all('%<h1>(.*)</h1>%', $leer, $arrayMaches);
        foreach ($arrayMaches as $result) {
            foreach ($result as $key) {
            }
        }
        $cortado=preg_split('%</?h1>%', $key);
        echo "<a href=".'"'.$escanear[$i].'"'."><li>".$cortado[0]."</li></a><hr>";                  
    }                               
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you output `$leer`? An HTML/XML parser might be an easier way to do this.

Comment: yep, the variable `$leer` gives me the entire page, so it´s getting the document correctly.

Comment: Could you explain quickly how to extract the title with an HTML parser? because i didn´t learn html parser that yet.

Comment: Here's a thread on that, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299033/getting-all-values-from-h1-tags-using-php. Your regex is greedy so if you have more than one `h1` on a line it's going to gobble all of that, or if you are using the `s` modifier (current code isn't using this).

Comment: i must say that there is only 1 `h1` tag in each document.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the DOM... you'll save yourself some trouble.

```
$menuData = array();
$iter = new DirectoryIterator('/home/sites/thetoptenweb.com/public_html/post');

foreach ($iter as $file) {
   if ($file->isFile()) {
       $filename = $file->getFilename();
       $path = $file->getPathname();
       $dom = new DOMDocument();
       $dom->loadHtmlFile($path);

       $titleNode = $dom->getElementsByTagname('h1')->item(0);
       if ($titleNode) {
          $title = $titleNode->nodeValue;
          $menuData[$filename] = $title;
       }
   }
}
```

Now you have all the stuff in `$menuData` you can just loop over it and output the links, assuming that the filename is the appropriate URL. Alternatively, you could output the links in the loop directly but it's wiser to separate things. Create a function to get the data you need, and then use that data to output.

But an even better solution would be to pick a blog platform and use that, then spend your time writing an importer and adjusting look and feel to suit.

Comment: So if i `print_r($menuData);`, i get an array like this ` [5cosasvivirsolo.php] =>` with just the filenames. How do i access to the `h1` title?. You said that i can loop over the `$menuData` variable but i don´t know where are the titles. Maybe you mean that i have to loop over the `$title array`?

Comment: If the `h1` just contained a basic title that should be in the array... do your `h1` contain additional markup? Also just saw that there was typo and corrected it.